# I'm trying to get all the badges on Arqade. Can you help me?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm trying to get all the badges. Can you help me through this journey?

Comment: Even if it wasn't against the spirit of the badges to ask for them, and even if you had say 100 people willing to help out and get you badges, *we can't do anything* unless you have questions or answers for us to actually interact with. A user account with no site interactions isn't going to get badges, rightfully earned or otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't get all the badges; some of them have been [retired](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Since most badges are (like reputation) earned by asking good questions or providing good answers to them, why don't you start there? You'll see that you'll 'automatically' get badges.

For more information, the background and purpose of badges, check the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/what-are-badges). Note that the badges you earn on Arqade Meta are counted separately.

Comment: ok but i just want support for this journey i'm going to go on

Comment: @WolfieChan This 'journey' meaning being an active member of the Arqade community? We will support you with that, as long as you as a member (just like the rest of us) are active and supportive yourself, trying to help improve the community. That way, and meanwhile, you will get badges as well as reputation by *earning* them, which is exactly why that system has been implemented, and why it works.